# Running python code as argument

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I want to know if using Python code as an argument to a command line program is possible under Windows.

As we can do in Linux e.g.

```
./a $(python version.py)
```

Comment: Can you use another shell or are you bound to `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Not well. You can abuse `for` to an extent, as [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/31/10334556.aspx) shows:

```
for /f %%i in ('python version.py') do a.exe %%i
```

But it is quite limited in comparison to what you can do under *nix.